# Javascript passing parameters

Tags: javascript

If I have the following code:

```
func({
    item: {
         subItem: 89
    },
    item2: {
         message: 'I want the item.subItem value to be inside this value as well'
    }
});
```

Is it possible to have `item.subItem` value passed into `item2.message` as well without doing any replacing within `func()`?

Comment: Why don't you just do this when you construct the object being passed into func?

Comment: As I understand your question, it has nothing to do with passing parameters. It seems like you want to define an object literal and have one property reference another, which is not possible, as far as I know. If that is what you want, you have to do what Jacob suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible unless you assign it from outside the object definition:

```
var obj = {
    item: {
         subItem: 89
    },
    item2: {}
};

obj.item2.message = 'I want the ' + obj.item.subItem + ' value to be inside this value as well';

func(obj);
```

Comment: I think the following would be slightly more elegant: `var shared=89; func({item: {subItem: {shared}}, item2: {message: 'I want to use ' + shared + ' here'}  )`

Answer (score 1):

No. They're independent objects. If you think you need this then make the object have a class that will allow it to do something useful (such as, say, templating).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var anItem = { subItem: 89 };

func({
    item: anItem
    },
    item2: {
         message: anItem
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in a direct way.. I would do it using:

```
function func(a)
    {
        alert(a);
    }
    func
    (
        new Item(10)
    ); 

    function Item(subItemVal)
    { 
            this.item = { subItem: subItemVal };
            this.item2 = { message: 'I want the ' + subItemVal + ' value to be inside this value as well' };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could do something like this to automatically replace all `item.XXX` substrings with corresponding entries in your item list:

```
function func(data) {
   for (var key in data.item)
      data.item2.message = data.item2.message.replace('item.'+key, o.item[key])
   print(data.item2.message) // I want the 89 value to be inside this value as well
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of why you would want to do this, but you could do something like this.

This is very hack'ish and I really wouldn't recommend it, but I think it does what you ask...?

*note: Better solutions have been provided.*

**[Live example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/Mx8cr/)**

```
func(test = {
    item: {
         subItem: 89
    },
    item2: {
         message: 'I want the item.subItem value to be inside this value as well'
    }
},test.item2.message += ' ' + test.item.subItem );


function func ( obj ) {
    alert( obj.item2.message );
}
```